# How to sort and get first obejct from array of objects get by joining multiple async javascript calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, request, call

I have a situation in which I am executing multiple async javascript Ajax request inside a for loop and getting result in json array of object asynchronously(not in a sequences) and then I have to cancat those array to make a single array.

So my questions is how can I sort the final array after getting last results of request raised from a loop and publish first record from array?
Because I am getting result asynchronously so I don't know which request will be processed at last?
And I can't use sync ajax request.

Thanks

Comment: If you can sort your array once all the async calls are done, why does the order of async calls matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
Promise.all([ 
    $.get('...url1'), 
    $.get('...url2')
]).then(onSuccess, onFailure);

function onSuccess(resultOfAllRequests) {
    // do something with the results of all requests
    // this won't be executed until all asynch requests are complete
    var resultOfRequest1 = resultOfAllRequests[0];
    var resultOfRequest2 = resultOfAllRequests[1];

    var singleArrayOfAllResponses = Array.prototype.concat.apply(Array.prototype, resultOfAllRequests);
    var sorted = singleArrayOfAllResponse.sort(function (a, b) {
       // this is numeric sorting. use your own sort logic
       return a - b;
    });
    var first = sorted[0]; // <-- this is what you wanted
}

function onFailure(resultOfAllRequests) {
    // one or many of the requests failed
    // handle the error(s) here
}
```

**Note:** Promises are not currently supported in Internet Explorer. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) is the complete list of browser support. There are many libraries that implement Promises for you that you can use if you need IE support. Most notably [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Angular.js also has its own promise implementation called [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).